# Why does [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; return a nil object

Tags: iphone

I have an iphone application with multiple views and related controllers and xib files. In the controller for the first view that is loaded I am trying to access the delegate for the application but the object that is returned is nil

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Any ideas why it would be nil?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because it is not (yet) set. The UIApplication delegate is usually instantiated and set from the MainWindow nib file. If you access it before the nib is loaded completely (e.g. an init method in a controller in the same nib), it is nil.

Comment: Thanks Nikolai, I moved the accessing of the delegate to a point where the application was fully loaded and it was no longer nil.

Answer (score 1):

It can also be because you are attempting to read `UIApplication.shared.delegate` from code within (or with code triggered from) the AppDelegate's init method.

`UIApplication.shared.delegate` is not set until after the AppDelegate's init method has returned.